# If $f$ is convex, is $\sup_x f(x,y)$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ convex. Let $g(y) = \sup_x f(x,y)$. Then is $g$ convex?

I can't find a counter example but I know that this holds true if we substitute $\inf$ for $\sup$, so I feel that it should not hold true.

Comment: If $\{f_i : i\in I\}$ is a family of convex functions from a convex set $C$  to $\mathbb{R}$, then the same is true for $f = \sup_{i\in I} f_i$.

Comment: As long as each $y \to f(x,y)$ is convex, the result is true. The epigraph of $g$ is the intersection of the epigraphs of $y \to f(x,y)$, from which it follows that $g$ is convex.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? If you are taking the supremum over all $x\in\mathbb R$, the supremum is only finite if $f$ is independent of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:D\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex on $D$ and assume there exists $c=c(y)\in \mathbb{R}$ 
$$f(x,y)\leq c(y)$$ for a fixed  all $(x,y)\in D$.

Now fix $(x,b)\in D\cap \big\{(x,y)\in D: y=b\big\},\;$ $\lambda \in [0,1].\;$ Since $f$ is convex on $D$ then
$$ f( (1-\lambda) (x,y)+\lambda (x,b)) \leq
 (1-\lambda) f(x,y)+\lambda f(x,b)) $$
Simply take the supremum over $x$ to get

$$ g( (1-\lambda) (y)+\lambda g(b)) \leq
 (1-\lambda) g(y)+\lambda g(b) $$
for every $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,y)\in D$. Since the line $y=b$ was chosen arbitrarily, then $g$ is convex.